# What is $L^2(X)\otimes L^2(Y)$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,\mu)$ and $(Y,\nu)$ measure space. We have that $$L^2(X\otimes Y)=\{f:X\times Y\to \mathbb R\mid \int_{X\times Y}|f(x,y)|^2d(\nu\otimes \mu)<\infty \}.$$

I know that sometimes it's homeomorphic to $L^2(X)\otimes L^2(Y)$, but I don't understand what is the space $L^2(X)\otimes L^2(Y)$. Any idea ? What $(f,g)\in L^2(X)\otimes L^2(Y)$ ? My first Idea would have been $f\in L^2(X)$ and $g\in L^2(Y)$, but I think this would be rather $L^2(X)\oplus L^2(Y)$ rather than the tensor product.

Comment: Do you mean $L^2(X\times Y)$ on the left hand side?

Comment: See about tensor product of abstract vector spaces. As you know what $L^2(X \otimes Y)$ is, you can obtain a relation between this and the vector space $L^2(X) \otimes L^2(Y)$.

Comment: Definitely not $L^2(X)\oplus L^2(Y)$. Need to use a Hilbert space version of tensor product for it to make sense too. There is an obvious map $L^2(X)\times L^2(Y)\to L^2(X\times Y)$ which sends $(f,g)$ to $f(x)g(y)$. Might be easier to see using $X=Y=S^1$ as an example. Then $L^2(S^1)$ is given by Fourier series, and $L^2(S^1\times S^1)$ is comprised of "double" summations (also Fourier series).